# How to interact the database and fetch data using Akka+Java

Tags: java, akka

My requirement is to fetch the data from database using our custom framework which was built on Akka + Java.

Am new to Akka and Am not able to get the Akka concepts- Promise, Future, ActorRef etc; I just gone through googling and code snippets, but am not clear on those .

I know this is not the place to ask for code snippet, but i was looking for a code snippet for hit the databse in akka and little explanation of the code snippet

So can you just let me know how to hit the database and fetch data from db and map to Java object in Akka with Java

Previous code:

```
    String query = "select * from Mytable where myid = ?";
    MyData myData= jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query ,
            new Object[] { myid},
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyData>(
                    MyData.class));

    return myData;
```

Comment: akka provides an implementation of the actor model which assists with isolating your database access so it can be performed asynchronously. As far as I'm aware though it doesn't provide a specific way for you to access a database though so you can happily make use of your existing techniques to do this. I use Spring's JDBC template in the same way as you show in your previous code snippet to access the database, it is just performed within an UntypedActor implementation to encapsulate the behaviour and improve the concurrency of the IO operations.

Comment: Can you modify the above code snippet by using akka so that i can get it

Comment: do you have the code of the actor where you want the database access to occur? If so I can adapt that for you.